# Mailscanner: how to block html attachments only

Tags: email, mailscanner, phishing

I have a `Mailscanner` site and I want to deny all *html* attachments but permit *html emails*.

AFAIK there is difference between *html attachments* and *html mail*: `Content-Disposition: attachment;`

I tried to configure `Filetype Rules = %etc-dir%/filetype.rules.conf` adding:

```
deny    html        No HTML attachments No HTML attachments allowed
```

But this blocks also *html emails*

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Mailscanner, it doesn't make distinction between inline and attachment entities.
You may want to submit an issue:
https://github.com/MailScanner/v5